# Xorg has been removed?

Tags: xorg, 23.10, display-manager

I stopped seeing `Ubuntu with Xorg` in my DE menu. I did not do or install anything out of the ordinary recently.

**Q:** Is this bad or good? How could have this happened? Finally, should I or should I not bring it back and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well seems like you didn't use it, no? As long as you don't miss anything (not using xrdp or sth. like this) its totally fine.

Ubuntu by default uses Gnome as display manager. Could be they just removed the default of installing xfce without specific usage.

Comment: So Xorg is not critical to the system or anything, right?

Comment: Jep, it's just an alternative desktop provider.

Comment: OK, thanks Jonas